# Assigning values to a vector using dplyr case when

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to assign vales to a named vector depending on the values in a df that I'm looping through by rows.  I see according to the documentation that the RHS of case when is a vector, whereas what I'm trying to do is to have the RHS be an actual assignment step.  Is this possible?  Case_when is really much more elegant here than having to use if statements:

```
test.df <- data.frame(cat1 = c('label1', 'label2', 'label3'), 
                  cat2 = c('label3', '', ''),
                  cat3 = c('', 'label2', 'label1'))

test.lst <- apply(test.df, 1, function(x){
                test.vec <- c(label1 = 0, label2 = 0, label3 = 0)

                case_when(
                  x[['cat1']]=='label1' | x[['cat2']]=='label1' | x[['cat3']]=='label1' ~ test.vec['label1'] <- 1,
                  x[['cat1']]=='label2' | x[['cat2']]=='label2' | x[['cat3']]=='label2' ~ test.vec['label2'] <- 1,
                  x[['cat1']]=='label3' | x[['cat2']]=='label3' | x[['cat3']]=='label3' ~ test.vec['label3'] <- 1
                )
              })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `transmute` function from the `dplyr` package to only keep the columns created/modified in the function call. So you can in affect create an entirely new dataframe. It would look like this:

```
test.lst <- test.df %>% 
  transmute(label1 = case_when(
    cat1 == "label1" | cat2 == "label1" | cat3 == "label1" ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  ),
  label2 = case_when(
    cat1 == "label2" | cat2 == "label2" | cat3 == "label2" ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  ),
  labels3 = case_when(
    cat1 == "label3" | cat2 == "label3" | cat3 == "label3" ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  ))
```

and your output would look like this:

```
  label1 label2 labels3
1      1      0       1
2      0      1       0
3      1      0       1
```

As a note, the `dplyr` package and most of its functions are vectorized. So they perform the desired operation on each of the rows already, without the need for a `for` loop or an `apply`/`map` function. This has the added benefits of speeding up your code and making it more readable.

Comment: Since each `case_when()` statement only has two cases, `if_else()` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

`case_when` are not necessary, here is an alternative solution:

```
sapply(paste0('label', 1:3), function(x) sign(rowSums(as.matrix(test.df) == x)) )
#      label1 label2 label3
# [1,]      1      0      1
# [2,]      0      1      0
# [3,]      1      0      1
```